# convert HH:mm to Date object in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have two times presented as strings like

```
14:10 and 19:02
```

how can I convert to Date object in order to get substracted value

```
var res = date1 - date2;
```

I tried to parse with

```
var date = new Date.parseExact(myDateVar, "HH:mm");
```

I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Date.parseExact is not a constructor

Comment: The [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) does not have any `parseExact()` method; where did you read about it? Whatever, if calculating the difference between two times is your ultimate goal I would not mess with dates.

Comment: There is no such built-in function. The `Date` class handles dates, not just times.

Comment: You don't need to parseExact, just pass a date/time string to the Date construct... e.g. date1 = new Date("01/01/1901 19:02")

Comment: Here's a fun way to convert the strings into dates :P `startDate = new Date(Date.prototype.setHours.apply(new Date(), '14:10'.split(':')));`

Answer (score 17):

You have several options:

## First option:

```
var date1 = new Date(null, null, null, 14, 10);
var date2 = new Date(null, null, null, 19, 02);
```

And you will get real date objects.

## Second option:

```
var date1 = new Date('01/01/1970 14:10');
var date2 = new Date('01/01/1970 19:02');
```

And you will get same result.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend messing with dates and all their oddities (time zones, bad APIs, daylight saving time, leap seconds...). For instance, if you want to calculate `"3:05" - "2:00"` and your script happens to run on the day there DST switch happens you may end up with results like `0:05` if you aren't carefull.

Fortunately, it's rather easy to parse a string with a time and convert it to a single unit that's easier to do maths with:

```js
// Most error checking omitted for brevity
const text = "23:59";
const parsed = String(text).match(/^(?<minutes>\d+):(?<seconds>\d+)$/);
if (parsed !== null) {
  const minutes = parseInt(parsed.groups.minutes, 10);
  const seconds = parseInt(parsed.groups.seconds, 10);
  const totalSeconds = 60 * minutes + seconds;
  console.log(
    "Input: %s; Minutes: %d; Seconds: %d; Total seconds: %d",
    text, minutes, seconds, totalSeconds
  );
}
```

You can calculate the difference between two times by calculating and then subtracting the corresponding `totalSeconds`. If you wrap this in a custom function or object you'll have something reusable. For example:

```js
// Most error checking omitted for brevity
function toSeconds(text) {
  const parsed = String(text).match(/^(?<minutes>\d+):(?<seconds>\d+)$/);
  if (parsed === null) {
    return null;
  }
  return totalSeconds = 60 * parseInt(parsed.groups.minutes, 10) + parseInt(parsed.groups.seconds, 10);
}

function toMinutesSeconds(totalSeconds) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
  const seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
  return String(minutes).padStart(2, "0") + ":" + String(seconds).padStart(2, "0");
}

const from = "14:10";
const to = "19:02";
const differenceInSeconds = toSeconds(to) - toSeconds(from);
console.log(
  "Total seconds: %s; MM:SS: %s",
  differenceInSeconds, toMinutesSeconds(differenceInSeconds)
);
```

It's also worth noting that, unlike date based solutions, this approach works with arbitrary durations (e.g. running time rather than time of the day).

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

```
var a="14:10";
var b="19:02";

var date1=new Date("01-01-2017 " + a + ":00");
var date2=new Date("01-01-2017 " + b + ":00");
//diff will be the number of milliseconds between the two times.
var diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
alert(diff);
```

of course this requires that you do its done within the same 24 hour period.

Answer (score 0):

first convert this : `14:10 and 19:02` to date

```
var
    pieces = "14:02".split(':')
    minute, second;

if(pieces.length === 2) {
    minute = parseInt(pieces[0], 10);
    second = parseInt(pieces[1], 10);
}
```

and use this :

```
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/15/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

Comment: I think you mean `pieces[0]`. How does the second snippet answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

[Date.parse in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

I think new Date.parseExact is in C# so there is no constructor in javascript;

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be based of the current datetime. I found a pretty simple solution to this. Parse out the HH:MM to hours and minutes and then replace current ISO string with regex.

```
function toDateFromHoursAndMinutesString(time: string) {
    const [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const dateStringIso = currentDate.toISOString();
    const replacedDateStringIso = dateStringIso.replace(/T.*/, `T${parseInt(hours)-1}:${minutes}:00.000Z`);
    return new Date(replacedDateStringIso);
}
```